# Qual a melhor logica para implementar sub-menu com eventos do mouse

Tags: jquery, html, css

Estou desenvolvendo este site e por enquanto não coloquei nenhum código JavaScript nele para torná-lo dinâmico.

Eu tenho um problema que se repete em todos os projetos por falta de conhecimento da linguagem e da lógica, problema seguinte:

Quando eu coloco o mouse em cima do `menu`, abre `sub-menu` mas ao tirar o mouse de cima do `menu` para tentar acessar o `sub-menu` como o `menu` perde o foco, o `sub-menu` desaparece antes que eu dê foco a algum item dele.

Toda vez acabo resolvendo com gambiarra mas gostaria de entender a lógica de resolver isto.

O código é normal:

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li>
        <a href="#">Categoria</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li>Sucategoria</li>
        </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Típico menu do Wordpress.

Eu percebi que isso acontece principalmente se o `sub-menu` tiver a uma margem do `menu`, problema que pode correr pelo fato do `sub-menu` precisar ganhar foco imediatamente após `menu` perder foco.

Comment: Poderia tentar colocar um `setTimeout` para executar sua função que faz o menu desaparecer após o evento `onfocusout` do menu

Comment: Acredito que você esteja mexendo no site, pois não está funcionando o mouseover e o tem um sub-menu que não some, ao invés de links use o StackSnippet e poste um exemplo do problema, leia: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 2):

Não entendi bem sua pergunta mas eu gosto de fazer isso com css apenas. O seu problema é que o menu não pode perder o foco senão o submenu desaparece mesmo. Sugiro você a "colar" o bloco do seu  com o bloco do seu submenu. Isso pode ser feito via posicionamento absoluto por exemplo. Ai no css você chama:

```
.menu ul li:hover a .sub-menu {
    display: block
}
```

O segredo mesmo consta em você "colar" o elemento que receberá o focus com o elemento do submenu, pois dai você poderá manter o submenu mesmo apos o menu perder o foco.

Comment: Não conheço a tag submenu em HTML.

Comment: Não existe tag submenu, o exemplo que dei pode ser qualquer classe.

Comment: Eu sei, era um pouco de sarcasmo, sem maldade, o que eu queria dizer é: O certo é `.sub-menu` conforme o exemplo do autor da pergunta.

Comment: Ah tá. Eu uso o exemplo de menu e submenu sempre. Agora que ví que menu era o nome da classe dele e dai faria sentido eu colocar sub-menu rs.